# Build Heroku from a node application "fail to detect" a buildpack

Tags: node.js, heroku, build, package.json

I reorganized my app and when I came to rebuild it onto my heroku server I got the following error

```
remote: ! ERROR: Application not supported by 'heroku/nodejs' buildpack remote: ! remote: ! The 'heroku/nodejs' buildpack is set on this application, but was remote: ! unable to detect a Node.js codebase.
```

I understand that this problem can be solved by re-arranging my folder structure. I do not want to do this as it is nicely organised as is. I want to find out how to solve the problem without restructuring my project.

current folder structure

```
\client\package.json
\client\node_modules
\client\{all other client files}

server\package.json
server\{all other server files}
server\none_modules
\wiki\{all wiki files}
.gitignore
```

### WHAT I HAVE TRIED

I have read articles suggesting to put a package.json in the root. I have tried an empty json file there called package.json but it didn't work as I guess it is actually using the file and it wants to read the one that is located in my \server directory to run the build scripts.

I was wondering if I could I just invoke heruku to start in a different directory?

### ATTEMPT 2

I tried creating a file called Procfile and added the following content to it

```
web: npm client
server: npm start
```

when I then created a commit and ran

```
git push heroku master
```

I got the following error

```
emote:  !     ERROR: Application not supported by 'heroku/nodejs' buildpack
remote:  !     
remote:  !     The 'heroku/nodejs' buildpack is set on this application, but was
remote:  !     unable to detect a Node.js codebase.
remote:  !         
remote:  !     A Node.js app on Heroku requires a 'package.json' at the root of
remote:  !     the directory structure.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     If you are trying to deploy a Node.js application, ensure that this
remote:  !     file is present at the top level directory. This directory has the
remote:  !     following files:
remote:  !     
remote:  !     client/
remote:  !     readme.md
remote:  !     server/
remote:  !     services/
remote:  !     wiki/
remote:  !         
remote:  !     If you are trying to deploy an application written in another
remote:  !     language, you need to change the list of buildpacks set on your
remote:  !     Heroku app using the 'heroku buildpacks' command.
remote:  !         
remote:  !     For more information, refer to the following documentation:
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#activation
remote: 
remote: 
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to infinite-refuge-86248.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/infinite-refuge-86248.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/infinite-refuge-86248.git'
```

For Reference below is my server JSON file

```
{
  "name": "Infoshot",
  "version": "0.0.4",
  "description": "Research Tool",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix ../client/",
    "clientinstall": "npm install --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\"  \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client "
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "config": "^3.2.2",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-validator": "^6.2.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.7.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.14",
    "nodemailer-sendgrid": "^1.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^4.1.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `Procfile` like the below to your root directory:

```
web: npm client
server: npm start
```

Comment: I created the file you described above and put it into my root and got this error when I attempted to deploy to heruku

Comment: remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/nodejs.tgz
remote:        
remote:  !     ERROR: Application not supported by 'heroku/nodejs' buildpack

Comment: I'll update the question with the full error and exactly what I did

Comment: see Attempt 2 in the doc for details